# Como agregar mas posiciones en cero a un array

Tags: php, array

amigos tengo este resultado

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["dato"]=>
    string(7) "3522.40"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["dato"]=>
    string(7) "6748.20"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["dato"]=>
    string(7) "7000.00"
  }
```

Insertar nuevos datos sería algo así:

```
[3]=>
array(1) {
   ["dato"]=>string(1) "0"
}
```

necesito poder agregarle mas campos al vector, después de la posición [2].

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, deberías indicar como deseas que quede el arreglo, luego de agregar más valores, pasa saber donde deseas ingresar la información.

Comment: Despues de la posicion [2], agregar mas campos que queden con valor cero, seria algo asi
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["dato"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
Gracias por las sugerencias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sería obtener el total de registros que posee el arreglo con la función `count` y luego asignar el nuevo valor en esa posición.

> Como desconozco el nombre de la variable que te genera el arreglo usare $a como referencia.

```
$posicion = count($a);  //Count devuelve la cantidad de registros que tiene el arreglo.


$a[$posicion]['dato'] = "0";  //Asigno en esa posición el valor que deseo almacenar.

var_dump($a);
```

> El var_dump($a) imprime lo siguiente:

```
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["dato"]=>
    string(7) "3522.40"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["dato"]=>
    string(7) "6748.20"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["dato"]=>
    string(7) "7000.00"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["dato"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, excelente tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Si tu array contiene índices numérico (es decir, no es un array asociativo) puedes hacer simplemente esto:

```
<?php
$a[] = ['dato' => 'loquesea'];
```

También está la función `array_push`, que hace exactamente lo mismo que el código de arriba:

```
<?php
array_push($a, ['dato' => 'loquesea']);
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, muy buen dato